# Immortan Joe and Rob Zombie's "Dragula" character similarity

Tags: character, analysis, mad-max-fury-road, music-video

While watching *Mad Max: Fury Road*, in the episode when Immortan Joe is riding his buggy, I got this instant feeling that the character looks familiar and I could relate it to [Rob Zombie's Dragula video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqQuihD0hoI). Is there any relationship/similarity between them?

Comment: In that George Miller and Rob Zombie are both film makers who love fantasy, maybe, but I don't know of any specific mention of Rob Zombie in any George Miller interviews.

Comment: I believe that it is "Dragula" not "Oragula".  You _are_ referring to the video from the "Hellbilly Deluxe" album released in 1998, correct?

Comment: @steelerfan thank you, I have corrected the question.

Comment: I thought that Immortan Joe looked quite like Grunchlk, Hugh Keays-Byrne's character from farscape